# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction In Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Thank you in advance

I am facing the below issue while updating the record in the Laravel.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction (SQL: update `tbl_name` set `status` = 0, `tbl_name`.`updated_at` = 2020-04-06 00:00:02)
```

My laravel code is like below.

```
try {
       app('db')->beginTransaction();
       TblNameModel::where('id', 1)->update(['status' => 0, 'updated_at' => '2020-04-06 00:00:02']);
       app('db')->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
       app('db')->rollback();
}
```

Comment: There is only one query in the transaction. Why do you want to run this query in a transaction?

Comment: @MDutt, Yes you are right, but what the actual issue is?

Comment: Is the the actual query that is causing the problem? If so then try to find out what the lock wait timeout value actually is in your database settings it might be set too low or you might have a bunch of cascading triggers on update which make this simple query take a long time to finish and exceed the lock timeout.

Comment: @apokryfos, actual query is not taking too much time.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

DB::beginTransaction();

try {
    $table = TblNameModel::find(1);
    $table->status = 0;
    $table->save();
} catch(\Exception $e){
    DB::rollback();
    throw $e;
}

DB::commit();
```

Comment: Okay @M Dutt, Thank you so much

Comment: catch the exception and throw it again?